# Is a hashtag valid in a header location redirect?

Tags: http, url, location

I think the hashtag fragment of an URL is not part of the HTTP protocol and therefore something like:

```
Location: http://domain.com/site/#hashtag
```

Is invalid.

But it still works on (some?) browsers and many people use it.

I can't find an official source which explicitly says yes or no to this case.

Is it valid or invalid use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid in an HTTP URI, and thus it is also valid in a Location header field.

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#rfc.section.7.1.2 for details.